# Clean way to search through hash keys in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash like so:

`hash = {"jonathan" => "12", "bob" => 15 }`

Then I have an array like so:

`array = ['jon', 'bob']`

I want to return the value of the key that includes a value in my array in the end.

The goal is something like this:

```
array.each do |name|
  if hash.key.include? name
  return hash.value
end
```

What's the best way to write that code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple values, use [`Hash#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
hash = {"jonathan" => "12", "bob" => 15 }
array = ['jon', 'bob']
hash.values_at(*array.select{|key| hash.has_key? key})
# => [15]
```

Using [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26):

```
hash.values_at(*(hash.keys & array))
# => [15]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the keys, you don't need a block, this will do:

```
hash.keys & array
```

This takes the keys of the hash and intersect it with the array.

Second part, get a value from the hash:

```
hash[(hash.keys & array).last]
```

This will get the last key that is shared in `hash` and `array` and returns the value of that key in `hash`.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `select` methods of `Hash`:

```
hash.select {| k,_ | array.include?( k ) }
# => {"bob"=>15}
```

and get, for example, last value:

```
hash.select {| k,_ | array.include?( k ) }.to_a.flatten.last
# => 15
```

or even use `values_at` method of `Hash`:

```
hash.values_at( *array ).compact.last
# => 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write :

```
hash = {"jonathan" => "12", "bob" => 15 }
array = ['jon', 'bob']
array.collect(&hash.method(:[])).compact # => [15]
```